# iOS Mail — HTML email signature renders too small

Tags: css, ios, email, html-email

Coding inline and with tables, I made a simple HTML e-mail signature that contains two images. When I send it from MacOS Mail several different clients, it works well on desktop. On iOS Mail, it shrinks down the size of the table, which is expected behavior, but it makes it significantly smaller than it needs to be, thus making my font-sizes tiny.

[image: IMG-8296.png]

The table has a 3 row, 2 column structure, two colored rows and one white one which has a colspan for full table width.

Things I have tested to no effect:

- more or less text content
- giving the cells a width in pixels
- giving the whole table width:100%
- marking images display:block or display:inline

Apparently iOS Mail thinks the table is wider than it is, or at least treats it that way.

When I remove the images the two columns become equally wide and the table fills the whole width. So I'm looking for a solution in how the images are styled; does anyone know if I can add some CSS or HTML attribute to the images to fix this?

Here's the code, stripped of some text styling to keep it legible:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
    <tr>
      <td valign=top style="background:#f9f2c8;padding:21px 20px 0 20px;vertical-align:top;">
        <div style="font-size:13px; ">
          <div style="font-size:16px;font-weight:600;">Name of the sender </div>
          <div>Description of the role of the sender</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td valign=top style="background:#96e7cf;padding:18px 20px 0 16px;vertical-align:top;">
        <img src='logo.png' width=124 height=41 alt="Org logo" style="width:124px;height:41px;display:inline;" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign=bottom style="background:#f9f2c8;padding:0 20px 20px 20px;vertical-align:bottom;">
        <div><img src='line.png' alt="divider" width=210 height=24 style="width:210px;height:24px;display:inline;" /></div>
        <div style="font-size:13px;">06 1234 5678</div>
      </td>
      <td valign=bottom style="background:#96e7cf;padding:0 20px 20px 20px;vertical-align:bottom;">
        <div style="font-size:14px; font-weight:600; white-space:nowrap;">tagline of the org</div>
        <div style="font-size:13px;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">organisation.nl</a></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=2 style="padding:20px;">
        <p style="font-size:13px;margin:0 0 8px 0; ">Werkzaam op maandag, dinsdag, woensdagmorgen, donderdag en vrijdag</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: _"but it makes it significantly smaller than it needs to be, thus making my font-sizes tiny"_ - how wide a table gets displayed, does not change how big the text content gets rendered - your "thus" here is in the wrong direction; more likely that the table gets rendered less wide, because the font renders smaller, and therefor the content does not need more space.

Comment: @CBroe In browsers that is certainly the case. My experience with iOS Mail is that it tries to make the content fit the width of the screen. It first squeezes the table until the images stop the columns from getting any narrower, then it scales the whole table and the font-sizes are scaled down accordingly.

Comment: Okay, then it does not decrease the font-size per se, but scales the whole thing - slightly different situation. Have you tried adding a viewport meta tag, that forbids scaling?

Comment: @CBroe Unfortunately, all <meta> tags are stripped out and CSS in <style> tags is inlined when the signature is copy-pasted or inserted into the email application's signature field. So options are really limited.

Answer (score 1):

First, make your table width 100%:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
```

That will make it fit the full width of its container.

Second, on the text-reduction, this whole table appears to only go down to about 415px. So if your mobile is smaller, it will scale it all as one group. To prevent that, make one or both of your images responsive. Here, I've made the divider responsive:

```
<div><img src="line.png" alt="divider" width="210" height="24" style="width: 100%;height: auto;display:inline;max-width: 210px!important;"></div>
```

I've added `!important` to the max-width because Outlook iOS has a default style that would change it 100% otherwise, potentially bloating your image.

Continue to use the width and height attributes because Outlook Windows desktop uses them.

Comment: Thank you for the insights! My problem was solved by adding width=100% to the table and the divider image and then style="max-width:… !important" to both (I don't want a full width table on desktop). To my surprise, the CSS width:100% needs to be omitted because when copy-pasting it is turned into a px value. Together this indeed keeps the table from scaling at all, which works fine on iOS in my case. I have yet to test it on Outlook.